# how to add a 'rate this app' button in my firefox os app?

Tags: firefox-os

I have uploaded an app in firefox app store. This app can be installed in firefox mobile os and firefox desktok browser.

How can I add 'rate this app' button and 'share' button in my application?

app link: https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/anti-mosquito

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a library for adding prompts to rate the application in an unobtrusive manner:

https://github.com/dcoloma/fxosRate

It's not exactly a "rate" and "share" button, but might serve the same purpose, or could be built-upon for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich Ayala :)